# Controller - Model in CodeIgniter and "Undefined property"

Tags: php, codeigniter

```html
<?php
class Success_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //insert into user table
    function get_all()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('session'); // = select * from session
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

```html
<?php 
class Success extends CI_Controller
{

     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('success_model');
    }

     public function index()
     {
        $data= $this->Success_model->get_all();
        $this->load->view('success_view', $data);     
      }
}
?>
```

As You can see this is good, but I have error:

```html
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Success::$Success_model

Filename: controllers/success.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\session\application\controllers\success.php
Line: 15
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\session\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once


Fatal error: Call to a member function get_all() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\session\application\controllers\success.php on line 15
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function get_all() on null

Filename: controllers/success.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:
```

I'm looking, and looking, but I dont know what is bad. The good directories are files, other classes are working but this not.

Please help. I'm just tired, because after 2 hours searching mistakes...

Comment: Umm, Your `success` controller doesn't even have 22 lines... My imagination is usually top-notch but unfortunately I cannot imagine the myterious line #22

Comment: My mistake, sory, I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CI v3, afaik

---

I think I see it:

```
$data= $this->Success_model->get_all();
```

Should be:

```
$data = $this->success_model->get_all(); // Notice the lowercase success_model
```

PHP variables are case-sensitive where as functions and class names are not.

---

One more solution would be to change

```
$this->load->model('success_model');
```

into

```
$this->load->model('Success_model');
```

because then you can use

```
$data= $this->Success_model->get_all();
```

Comment: But if is class Success_model why I should here use success_model (this works) it is not logical for me

Comment: It all boils down to the fact that class names and function names are case-insensitive in PHP so behind the scenes CodeIgniter essentially does this `$this->{strtolower($model_name)} = new success_model();`. You can check out `/system/core/loader.php` and find `function model()` if you want to get into the nitty-gritty details. Class properties (aka variables) however, are case-sensitive.

Comment: Although model file can be loaded if used each (uppercase or lowercase) accordingly, library file can be loaded if used lowercase only. I am making distinction in own code that for models I always use uppercase $this->load->model('Some_m');$this->Some_m->some_method(); and for libraries lowercase $this->load->library('some_lib');$this->some_lib->some_method();.

Comment: @Tpojka I've updated my answer to reflect your comment, thank you.